# NSMatrix and autoresize only certain cells?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I have an NSMatrix with two columns,  When the frame resizes I don't want the left column to resize with it.  Is there a way to do this without subclassing NSMatrix?

I am thinking maybe I should just make two NSMatrix's and position them side-by-side, one with autoresizing set to YES and one set to NO.  Is this the most appropriate way to do it?

Thanks for any help.

P.S. This site has been incredibly helpful.  Thank you everybody for contributing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without (heavily) subclassing? No - NSMatrix is a uniform grid control.

Regarding two NSMatrix instances side-by-side, you'd then lose the main functionality of a matrix (treating the action cells as a group). If all you're trying to do is line up a small number of yes/no controls, do it without the matrix.